# Referencing a plugin from a theme in nopCommerce no longer working in 4.60

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

We have this large solution built in nopCommerce where we have 2 plugins and one custom theme.

I'm currently upgrading from 4.3 to 4.6 which means changing everything to async in service references (in the plugin) along with some other braking changes.

Both plugins are now upgraded but I have issues in the theme where I no longer can reference classes from the plugins.

Below is a sample of how _CheckoutAttributes.cshtml is layed out. It's located in Nop.Web/Themes/ThemeName/Views/Shared.

I've changed some of the naming to "ProjectName" to keep privacy.

```
@using System.Text
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Media
@using Nop.Services.Media
@using Nop.Services.Orders
@using Nop.Core
@using Nop.Plugin.Misc.ProjectName.Services
@inject IDownloadService downloadService
@inject CatalogSettings catalogSettings
@inject ICheckoutAttributeService checkoutAttributeService
@inject IStoreContext _storeContext
@inject IProjectNameCheckoutAttributeService projectNameCheckoutAttributeService
@inject IWebHelper _webHelper

@{
    var checkoutAttributes = projectNameCheckoutAttributeService.GetCheckoutAttributes();
}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="checkout-attributes-form">

etc...
```

The error I get is **The type or namespace name 'Plugin' does not exist in the namespace 'Nop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

This used to work in nopCommerce 4.3 but no matter what I try now (clean, rebuild etc) it wont build.

In 4.3 the Intellisense actually gave the same error but the compilation of the project/solution still was successful.

**Any input on how to solve this?**

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, restarting Visual Studio, keeping the cshtml files closed.

I've also tried referencing other standard plugins to see if it's a problem relating to only my plugins. But that also failed.

It seems like nopCommerce 4.6 or perhaps rather dot.net core 7 is more strict about being able to compile the razor files. Or perhaps it has something to do with Visual Studio?

I looked into if I can choose to only compile the razor files when loading them but can't seem to find a way to turn off building them at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure I have an answer, but one thought is that your `ProjectNameCheckoutAttributeService` could inherit from the Nop `CheckoutAttributeService`, and then you override the `GetCheckoutAttributes()` method. Then in your plugin's NopStartup class you register your `ProjectNameCheckoutAttributeService` to be used when the `ICheckoutAttributeService` is called. If you do this, you only have to reference Nop libraries in your theme as the `ICheckoutAttributeService` is part of the Nop libraries.

Comment: The SendinBlue and Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip plugins override a Nop service. Though these plugins are not overriding the same service you need to, I think they can be used to guide you.

Comment: @quaabaam Thanks so much for commenting. This is the case for many of the services but unfortunately I also have many cases where the servica also introduces new methods that don't exist in the nopCommerce interfaces :(

Answer (score 0):

The service "IProjectNameCheckoutAttributeService projectNameCheckoutAttributeService" is a service class of the plugin "Nop.Plugin.Misc.ProjectName.Services", if I understand correctly. Looks to me, since the plugin isn't added to Nop.Web as a dependency, the files inside Nop.Web can not access the files from your plugin.

Now if you do add it, it'll most likely create a circular dependency if Nop.Web is referenced inside your plugin. In this case, you should not do this.

A workaround I can think of, is to override this view inside your plugin, and do your code there.

If the original file path is this: `Nop.Web/Themes/ThemeName/Views/Shared/ _CheckoutAttributes.cshtml`, override it inside your plugin following the same folder structure:  `YourPlugin/Themes/ThemeName/Views/Shared/_CheckoutAttributes.cshtml`

For this to work, you'll need to add the ViewLocationExpander and other necessary stuff inside your plugin as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: A bit late but thanks for your answer!